# Animation sequence for SplashScreen inside AsyncTask doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, android-animation

I want to run animation sequence in splash screen as startup data are loading to the app. Before I put animation into `asyncTask`, it worked perfectly, but animation should not be running before startup data are loading. So I made `asyncTask` API call for this. Inside `onPreExecute()` I want to start animation sequence and in `doInBackground()` is `startupRequest()`.

Problem with this solution -> If I start splash screen animation will start(I checked it) but it immediately froze as I move to `doInBackground()` method --> the second animation is not called.

I even tried to do call animation inside `runOnUiThread()` method(which is useless, because onPreExecute() should run on UI Thread - it's for `ProgressBar` or stuff like that).

AsyncTask call and Animation method:

```
fun splashScreen(splashActivity: Splash){
        class GetSplashAsync: AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

            override fun onPreExecute() {
                createLog("SplashScreen: ", "Starting onPreExecute() --> anim on UIThread")
                splashActivity.runOnUiThread {
                    splashActivity.splashAnimation()
                }
            }

            override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Boolean {
                return splashActivity.startupRequest()
            }

        }

        GetSplashAsync().execute()
    }


fun splashAnimation(){

        val firstAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.splash_first_anim)
        val secondAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.splash_second_anim)

        firstAnimImg.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        secondAnimImg.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        createLog("SplashScreenAnim: ", "Starting anim 1")
        firstAnimImg.startAnimation(firstAnim)


        firstAnim.setAnimationListener(object: Animation.AnimationListener{
            override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {
                firstAnimImg.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {

            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
                createLog("SplashScreenAnim: ", "Starting anim 2")
                secondAnimImg.startAnimation(secondAnim)
            }

        })

        secondAnim.setAnimationListener(object: Animation.AnimationListener{
            override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {
                secondAnimImg.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {

            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
            }

        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing sequence of execution like below in method `splashAnimation()`:

```
fun splashAnimation(){

    val firstAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.splash_first_anim)
    val secondAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.splash_second_anim)

    firstAnimImg.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    secondAnimImg.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

    firstAnim.setAnimationListener(object: Animation.AnimationListener{
        override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {
            firstAnimImg.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {

        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
            createLog("SplashScreenAnim: ", "Starting anim 2")
            secondAnimImg.startAnimation(secondAnim)
        }

    })

    secondAnim.setAnimationListener(object: Animation.AnimationListener{
        override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {
            secondAnimImg.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {

        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
        }

    })

    createLog("SplashScreenAnim: ", "Starting anim 1")
    firstAnimImg.startAnimation(firstAnim) //Started this animation at last after setting up all animation listener, be sure if you've duration in xml. 
}
```